# Opencart Missing Orders: $this->model_checkout_order->addOrderHistory(...) not being executed

Tags: php, apache, model-view-controller, opencart, opencart-3

Every incoming order's order status can't be updated. Any default extension such as `cash on delivery` and any controller that runs `$this->model_checkout_order->addOrderHistory(...);` is not executing. However, *it seems that events are being fired for order emails are still being received. ?*

Even on the admin area, updating the missing order's status or any order is not working. I have tried duplicating the function `addOrderHistory` to `testOrderHistory` (with the very same contents) and updated every call from `$this->model_checkout_order->addOrderHistory(...);` to `$this->model_checkout_order->testOrderHistory(...);` and it seems to work now.

However I would like to avoid editing core files just to fix it. Is there any other way? It also feels wrong to just change all core files from `$this->model_checkout_order->addOrderHistory(...);` to `$this->model_checkout_order->testOrderHistory(...);`

I have also checked both server logs and opencart logs and I can't find anything of relevance.

I have also tested returning strings from both `testOrderHistory()` and `addOrderHistory()` and proceeds to log them. Logging works fine at the `controller`'s end but `$this->model_checkout_order->addOrderHistory(...);` always returns a `bool(true)` rather than the string I've been trying to return. However `$this->model_checkout_order->testOrderHistory(...);` seems to return the string correctly.

I'm stucked, It would be nice if you guys can shed me some light with regards to this. Thanks~

Using opencart 3.0.3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it. `$this->model_checkout_order->addOrderHistory(...);` was not being called because I've added another custom function that listens on event `addOrderHistory/before` that returns a boolean. This in turn halts the sequence.

I did not know that there are controllers that must not return a value especially if it is listening on an event.